# how to append 2 different images based on time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, frontend, web-frontend

This is my code so far:

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getHours();
var img = new Image();
var img2 = new Image(); 
var div = document.getElementById('geometry2');

img.onload = function() {
 if (time < 12) {
  div.appendChild(img);
 };
else {
  div.appendChild(img2);
}

img.src = 'images/morning.png';
img2.src = 'images/other.png';
```

I am not sure what my mistake is, but neither one of the images is displaying. This it the code for the HTML element it is referring to:

```
    <img src="images/geometry.png" id="geometry2" alt="">
```

Comment: don't think the ; after first if block is necessary. Maybe it's "closing" the if, and the ELSE never executes and throws a compile error (see console). Where is the script called ? head section ? script tag inside html ? are you sure the dom is loaded ?

Comment: its in a separate JS file

Comment: Well, your event handler should probably be on `div.onload` instead of `img.onload`, and as @Pierre suggested, perhaps it needs to be loaded after the rest of the DOM (i.e., just before `</body>`).

Comment: You're assigning the value of `src` after you append the image to the document. When the image is added to the document it won't have a source.

Comment: I tried all of those solutions...still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

**A few mistakes here:**

- Closing the `if/else` with a semi-colon this will give a javascript
  error in the console and stop any further execution of your code
- Not closing the function for the `onload` event with curly brace -
  this will do the same as above
- You are trying to append an `image` to an `image` - an `image` is not a
  collection of images, it is a single `image` with a `src` (source)

**Fixes:**

- Close the function correctly
- Remove the semi-colon after the `if`
- Give the `div` an `id`
- Get the `div` in javascript
- Append the `image` to the `div`

**Fixed code:**

```
<div id="divImages">
    <img src="../images/geometry.png" id="geometry2" alt="">
</div>

<script>        
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours();
    var img = new Image();
    var img2 = new Image();
    var div = document.getElementById('divImages');

    img.onload = function () {
        if (time < 12) {
            div.appendChild(img);
        }
        else {
            div.appendChild(img2);
        };

    img.src = '../images/morning.jpg';
    img2.src = '../images/other.png';
</script>
```

Comment: I greatly simplified my code:
`var d = new Date();
var time = d.getHours();
var image;
if (time < 12) {
    document.write("<img src='../images/morning.png'>");
}
else {
    document.write("<img src='../images/other.png'>");
}`

Comment: The problem, I realized, is that the image folder is actually not IN the js directory, but rather, in the main directory. so I used ".." to go back. unfortunately, while the code seems to work just fine when I add something else in as a test, the images are not loading. is there something wrong with using "img src='../images/other.png" to refer to the image??

Comment: Hi @poopyh3ad, can you put up the full code of what you have currently?
I'm not sure what your folder structure is, whether you are including the script from an external file or it's in the HTML file itself etc.
Cheers.